# text expression of while loop is not working in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am taking input p1 and p2 , one should be X and one should be O in any order.
i use while loop for it. I guess i am not doing any mistake with the text expression , i dont know why its not working .

i really need someone to check

```
def players():
    p1=p2=""
    while((p1!="X" and p2!="O")or(p1!="O" and p2!="X")):
        p1=input("enter p1:").upper()
        p2=input("enter p2:").upper()
    print(p1,p2)
players()
```

when i tried p1=X and p2=O or vice versa , the loop did not terminated as it should according to the condition

when i tried p1=X,p2=X and p1=O,p2=O , the loop terminated

i did not understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: The condition very specifically says to continue as long as they are not the same or invalid. Do you mean `while p1 not in ['X', 'O'] or p2 not in ['X', 'O']:` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say `p1 == "X"` and `p2 == "O"`. The first condition is false, but the second condition is true, so the loop continues.

A simpler expression for the condition you want would be

```
while p1 not in "XO" or p2 not in "XO" or p1 == p2:
```

The first ensures that `p1` is either `X` or `O`; the second ensures the same for `p2`, and the third ensures that both players did not choose the same marker.

Since there are only two valid choices, the first choice forces the second, so there's no reason for the second prompt:

```
while True:
    p1 = input("enter p1: ").upper()
    if p1 in "XO":
        break
p2 = "O" if p1 == "X" else "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example of p1=X and p2=O, the second condition will evaluate to true. This makes your while evaluate to `while( (false) or (true))`. Since one of them is true the loop continues.

See this link for information about while loops: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are more efficient ways to do this but I tried to preserve your code as much as possible:

```
def players():

   p1, p2 = "",""

   options = ["X","O"]

   while True:

        p1_choice = input("enter p1:").upper()

        p2_choice = input("enter p2:").upper()

        if p1_choice or p2_choice not in options:

            break

        else:

            # Do whatever here
```

Comment: `p1_choice or p2_choice not in options` looks fishy. If `p1_choice` is any valid string, the condition will pass. Is this what we really want now? Hmm...

Comment: @TrebledJ it's invalid as written, as `not in` binds more tightly than `or` producing `if p1_choice or (p2_choice not in options):`

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is almost valid:

- You're testing whether they don't match, rather than do... swapping `!=` to `==` fixes this. This fixes invalid inputs (like `L` or `R` from passing).
- The condition is reversed, you need to `not` the result. This fixes the condition being the reverse of what you expect. The result of both changes is:

  `while not ((p1 == "X" and p2 == "O") or (p1 == "O" and p2 == "X")):`

Note this is basically readable in English: While not X and O or O and X.

We can test this, remembering that `True` means try again:

```
p1 = "L"; p2 = "R"; print not ((p1 == "X" and p2 == "O") or (p1 == "O" and p2 == "X"))
True
p1 = "X"; p2 = "X"; print not ((p1 == "X" and p2 == "O") or (p1 == "O" and p2 == "X"))
True
p1 = "O"; p2 = "O"; print not ((p1 == "X" and p2 == "O") or (p1 == "O" and p2 == "X"))
True
p1 = "O"; p2 = "X"; print not ((p1 == "X" and p2 == "O") or (p1 == "O" and p2 == "X"))
False
p1 = "X"; p2 = "O"; print not ((p1 == "X" and p2 == "O") or (p1 == "O" and p2 == "X"))
False
```

Some of the other examples give better methods of doing this, but this is what is wrong with your current code.